# Why is memory below the stack pointer constantly being overwritten under a debug session?

Tags: ms-dos, assembly, x86, debugging

When I run a debug session using FreeDOS and `DEBUG.EXE`, I get a session like the following.  I've added a description of what I saw as annotation on the image.  Each step, I've printed out the stack contents.  What's very confusing is why the stack is changing *at all* given the commands I am running – such as simple moves between registers.

Step 1: move AX into DS, and mysteriously, something starts eating the stack!  what gives?

```
MOV DS, AX
```

Step 2: move a literal 0 value into DX, and weirdly a couple values on the stack start to change.  Why on Earth is this happening?

```
MOV DX, 0000
```

... and so on.  Look closely at the image to see how things change from step to step.

If anyone has a clue, I'd love to hear it.

[image: debug session]

Comment: This is probably off-topic here, even if you are using retro tooling.

Comment: What's retro about this is the reliance of interrupt service routines on the user's stack.  Modern processors tend to have alternative hardware mechanisms for this, such a shadow stack pointer register that is switched to while entering in supervisor mode to service interrupts.  From today's point of view, it would be bad form for the OS to have rely on the user program maintaining a proper stack pointer register and adequate stack space for servicing interrupts, given that a modern OS is protecting itself and other processes against malicious or accidental behaviors.

Comment: @ErikEidt I don't think that's enough to justify this as a "retrocomputing" question. The reason why this is happening is not "because you are using a retro OS", but because "you cannot rely on the memory below the stack pointer not changing". For example, I can imagine a "modern" OS where if those bytes are in a different page, they could go from "00" to "page not present" in between instructions (I don't know if that can happen in Windows; it would not occur to me to care because "I don't rely on the memory below the SP not changing").

Comment: Sure, you don't want to rely on memory below the SP in general.  However, the OP is not attempting to rely on memory below the SP, but rather understand this observed behavior relative to mere debugging.  And I'm asserting that this particular behavior, due to its antiquated interrupt handling mechanism, is a "retro".

Comment: @EuroMicelli: Actually, modern PC platforms have made it "officially" safe for a function which doesn't use the stack or call other functions to use up to (IIRC) 512 bytes beyond the stack pointer for local variables without having to adjust SP before and after doing so, and so the fact that such usage isn't safe everywhere is verging on "retro".  Further, on most modern debug platforms it is safe for code to abuse the stack pointer while interrupts are disabled, but the design of MS-DOS DEBUG isn't modern.

Comment: If you provide the test program we could recreate the session in FreeDOS Debug/X or [my fork lDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug) and figure out what gets written to the stack. Look at the [intr1 entry](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/e3b083561c33/source/run.asm#l6028) and [intrtn function](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/e3b083561c33/source/run.asm#l6187) of lDebug, or Debug/X's [intr03 entrypoint](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/cd9b37f9ccc5/TRAPR.INC#l158) or [the intrtn](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/version-1.25/DEBUG.ASM#l7804) of Debug/X v1.25

Comment: @ecm This was a program on page 183 from "Assembly Language Step by Step", by Jeff Duntemann, published 1992.  I found a [PDF copy](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~clac/infra_de_software/Assembly%20Language%20Step%20by%20Step%201992.pdf), where it is on page 204.

Comment: @ByronKatz Actually this seems to be eat2.asm from page 243 of the PDF. I had to change the two lines similar to `lea dx, Eat1` to `mov dx, offset Eat1` to make `jwasm -Zm eat2.asm` \ `warplink eat2` create what I assume is the same executable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note all your references to changing values are *below* the stack pointer, actually a free space. You are not expected to care about this area (stack grows towards lower addresses), as this is of no concern to your application.

Even if your computer is sitting at a debugger prompt and apparently is inactive, it isn't. It constantly runs through interrupt service routines, like the timer (or other peripherals) interrupt routines that constantly use stack memory, others will be the result of the debugger itself frequently looking for keypresses - What you see is simply the leftovers of these frequent activities in the free space of the stack (which is absolutely irrelevant for your application - The part of the stack your application is working with is *above* the stack pointer). Thus, the values you see are areas of free space that have been used and changed by such system routines, as you are sharing the stack with these routines. And, BTW, it is absolutely irrelevant what your appliction is doing in a debug step - These areas might also change if you are not even stepping through your own code.

The only thing you hopefully will never observe is *values changing at and above the stack pointer* or intermittent changes *of the stack pointer itself* because this is where your program's working memory is.

Comment: I guess I'm just surprised that even in this scenario, it would be necessary for applications to use memory so close to my own.  I guess I was thinking it would somehow use more distant memory, sort of "outside" my memory space.

Comment: @ByronKatz: More modern debugging tools will often avoid disturbing anything near the application's stack, but doing that requires that either the processor has a separate stack pointer for the application and the debugger, or that the debugger emulates the behavior of a virtual CPU, which in the absence of hardware support would totally dog performance [probably by at least an order of magnitude].

Comment: @supercat this is not so much s function of the debugging tool, but rather of the OS, where the stack is, is normally not determined by the debugger.

Comment: @tofro: Debuggers often virtualize some aspects of system behavior.  If the debugger virtualizes the stack, it can put it somewhere that it won't get stomped.  On the 8088/8086, the only way a debugger could virtualize the stack would be to emulate instruction execution.  Such a thing may be possible, but would be quite expensive.  An 80386-specific debugger which is intended for use only with 8086-based code, however, could virtualize the stack much more cheaply.

Comment: @supercat I wouldn't want my debugger to put the stack somewhere else than the program stand-alone would put it - It stops being debugging once the debugger changes the behavior of the program. And I actually have never experienced one that did. Can you give a concrete example of one of those debuggers?

Comment: And how would you debug a program that accidentally runs the stack over its own data or even program segment with a debugger like that?

Comment: @tofro: From the point of view of the executing program, the debugger would put the stack where the OS loader would put it given what memory was available when the program started.  If the debugger is acting as a VM, however, the addresses seen by the program need not bear any relation to any address seen by anything else other than debugger UI features to inspect memory contents.

Comment: @supercat I repeat: If you get me a debugger that acts as a VM without support from the OS, I would agree. As far as it stands. I cannot. I don't know of any debugger that does (or did). And again: If a debugger would prevent a common cause of program failure like the stack overflowing into other important data, I would count it as useless. Notwithstanding weird programs that could actually be *using* such behavior.

Comment: @tofro: I think "dosbox" can be built to include a debugger, though I've not used that feature; it certainly acts as a VM.  The 80386 version of Borland's Turbo Debugger uses virtual 8086 mode to provide debugging features when running real-mode DOS programs in versions of DOS that know nothing about virtualization.

Comment: TD386 used virtual mode to be able to use memory above 1M for the debugger code itself (enabling debugging of programs that largely filled DOS memory space, with a close-to-zero footprint of the debugger in conventional memory) - To my knowledge, it had none of the features you mentioned. And, I would still be annoyed if it would move my stack around.

Comment: @ByronKatz *I'm just surprised that even in this scenario, it would be necessary for applications to use memory so close to my own.* How can you be surprised, when that's precisely how interrupt handling is implemented by the CPU? Every time an interrupt occurs, the CPU pushes the flags and CS:IP on the stack. So even if the interrupt handler did switch stacks, there'll be the leftovers of flags and CS:IP left. Even on a bare-bones no-DOS IBM 5150 running BASIC, the timer tick interrupt handler runs 18.2 times per second :)

Answer (score 4):

The cause of this change is the fact that you are using the 't' command to step through instructions.  That command makes use of a CPU interrupt to regain control after the instruction completes.  That interrupt stores state on the stack before transferring control to the interrupt handler.  The state on the stack is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

According [to the comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6540/why-is-memory-below-the-stack-pointer-constantly-being-overwritten-under-a-debug?noredirect=1#comment105409_6540) I recreated the same program by copying the source from page 243 [of the PDF of Assembly Language Step by Step](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/%7Eclac/infra_de_software/Assembly%20Language%20Step%20by%20Step%201992.pdf):

```
MyStack SEGMENT STACK
    db 64 dup ('STACK!!!')
MyStack ENDS

MyData SEGMENT
Eat1    db "Eat at Joe's...",'$'
Eat2    db "...ten million flies can't ALL be wrong!",'$'
CRLF    db 0Dh,0Ah,'$'
MyData ENDS

MyProg SEGMENT
    assume CS:MyProg,DS:MyData
Main    Proc
Start:
    mov ax, MyData
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset Eat1
    call Writeln
    mov dx, offset Eat2
    call Writeln

    mov ah, 4Ch
    mov al, 0
    int 21h

Write   PROC
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ret
Write   ENDP

Writeln PROC
    call Write
    mov dx, OFFSET CRLF
    call Write
    ret
Writeln ENDP

Main    ENDP
MyProg  ENDS

    END Start
```

Note that I replaced the uses of `lea dx,` by `mov dx, offset` which older MASM versions may have done automatically. I then assembled this program using [JWasm](https://github.com/Baron-von-Riedesel/JWasm/releases) and linked it using [WarpLink](https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/warplink.zip):

```
E:\>jwasm -Zm eat2.asm
JWasm v2.18, Apr  9 2023, Masm-compatible assembler.
Portions Copyright (c) 1992-2002 Sybase, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Source code is available under the Sybase Open Watcom Public License.

eat2.asm: 43 lines, 2 passes, 2 ms, 0 warnings, 0 errors
E:\>warplink eat2

WarpLink 2.61 (05/11/93 Alpha) Copyright 1989-93 Michael Devore.
All rights reserved.


E:\>load image size: 001K
E:\>
```

Next I ran this file in [lDebug](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug):

```
E:\>ldebug eat2.exe
lDebug (2024-03-29)
-re.append @dw ss:(sp - 11) & ~0F 200 - 1
-re
AX=0000 BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A2D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0000 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0000 B85D2A            mov     ax, 2A5D
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 0000 STACK!!!STACK!..
-t
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A2D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0003 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0003 8ED8              mov     ds, ax
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 0000 2A5D-0000 0003 2A61 3246 STAC..]*....a*F2
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0005 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0005 BA0000            mov     dx, 0000
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 0003 2A5D-0000 0005 2A61 3246 STAC..]*....a*F2
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0008 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0008 E81100            call    001C
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 0005 2A5D-0000 0008 2A61 3246 STAC..]*....a*F2
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=001C NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:001C E8F8FF            call    0017
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 2A5D 0000-001C 2A61 3246 000B STAC]*....a*F2..
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FC BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0017 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0017 B409              mov     ah, 09
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 2A5D 0000 0017-2A61 3246 001F 000B ST]*....a*F2....
-
AX=095D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FC BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0019 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0019 CD21              int     21
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  0017 095D 0000 0019-2A61 3246 001F 000B ..].....a*F2....
-
Eat at Joe's...AX=0924 BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FC BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=001B NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:001B C3                retn
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 0924 0000-0266 0000 0000 0000 STAC$...f.......
2A3D:01F0  0000 2A5D 2A2D 001C-2A61 3246 001F 000B ..]*-*..a*F2....
-
```

Now let's examine each step in turn:

```
-re
AX=0000 BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A2D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0000 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0000 B85D2A            mov     ax, 2A5D
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 0000 STACK!!!STACK!..
```

This is the initial state of the program. The zero just below `ss:sp` is from where DOS stores the value for `ax` during program loading. (The debugger automatically retrieves this value and uses it to initialise its `reg_eax` variable.)

```
-t
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A2D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0003 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0003 8ED8              mov     ds, ax
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 0000 2A5D-0000 0003 2A61 3246 STAC..]*....a*F2
```

Let's examine the code that causes these stack writes. First, there's [the interrupt 1 (single-step trace interrupt) entrypoint](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/e3b083561c33/source/run.asm#l6027) of the debugger:

```
        ; Interrupt 01h (single-step interrupt) handler.
iispentry intr1, 0, sharedentry1
    lframe int
    lenter
    push ax
```

The first three words are the interrupt stack frame's `fl`, `cs`, and `ip` in order, the 3246h is the flags, 2A61h is the code segment, and 0003h is the instruction pointer. This points at the next instruction, the `mov ds, ax` (same one as displayed by the register dump).

Then there's a 0000h. This is the `bp` value pushed by the `lenter` macro (from [my macro collection lmacros2.mac](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/e611130fc291/lmacros2.mac#l473)). Then we get 2A5Dh which is the value of `ax` after the first instruction ran.

After the `intr1` entrypoint is done, it branches to [the shared `intrtn` function](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/e3b083561c33/source/run.asm#l6187):

```
        ; Common interrupt routine.

        ; Housekeeping.
intrtn:
    cli             ; just in case
    pop word [cs:reg_eip]       ; recover things from stack
    pop word [cs:reg_cs]
    pop word [cs:reg_efl]
    mov word [cs:reg_ds], ds    ; ! word-aligned (AC flag)
    mov word [cs:reg_eax], ax   ; ! word-aligned (AC flag)
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax          ; => lDEBUG_DATA_ENTRY
%ifn _RUN_ENTRY_SECTION
    ; (elided because this is code is not used)
%else
    jmp intrtn_entry
%endif
```

This eventually stores away the values of `ss` and `esp` then sets both to address different stacks in the debugger stack segment:

```
    mov word [reg_ss], ss   ; save stack position
_386    and word [reg_eip+2], byte 0    ; we're from real mode
    _386_o32        ; mov dword [reg_esp], esp
    mov word [reg_esp], sp
    mov ss, ax      ; mov ss, cs    ; (don't use the stack here)

; ...

    mov word [ss:reg_ds], ds    ; ! word-aligned (AC flag)
    mov word [ss:reg_eax], ax   ; ! word-aligned (AC flag)
    mov ax, ss
    mov ds, ax      ; mov ds, ss
@@:
%endif
    mov ax, 2
%ifn _ONLY386
    _386_jmps .386          ; -->
; ...

.386:
[cpu 386]
    mov esp, reg_gs+2
```

Then there's another zero, which is actually from when the debugger entered the application (before the application instruction ran). This is [in the run function](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/e3b083561c33/source/run.asm#l5868):

```
    mov byte [bInDbg], 0
    _386_o32        ; push dword [reg_efl]
    push word [reg_efl]
    _386_o32        ; push dword [reg_cs]   ; high word is zero
    push word [reg_cs]
    _386_o32        ; push dword [reg_eip]
    push word [reg_eip]
    test byte [reg_efl+1], 2    ; IF set?
    mov ds, word [reg_ds]       ; restore ds
    jz .di
    sti             ; required for ring3 protected mode if IOPL==0
.di:
%if _ONLYNON386
    iret
%else
..@patch_no386_iret_code_or_entry:
    o32         ; iretd
    iret                ; jump to program
%endif
```

On a 386 CPU, this actually restores `efl`, `cs`, and `eip`. The high word for `cs` is ignored and `eip` generally must be < 64 KiB in Real/Virtual 86 Mode. But the high word of `efl` should be preserved by the debugger so an `o32 iret` (also called `iretd`) is required.

Anyway, on running the instruction at address 0, the debugger pushes the `efl` dword to `dword [ss:1FCh]`, the `cs` dword to `dword [ss:1F8h]`, and the `eip` dword to `dword [ss:1F4h]`. So the `word [ss:1F4h]` gets the value of `ip` that the debugger returns to, which is 0000h for the very first trace step.

And on. Note that I entered an empty line to lDebug, which automatically repeats the prior T command. (Recent versions of FreeDOS Debug/X share this feature.)

```
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0005 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0005 BA0000            mov     dx, 0000
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 0003 2A5D-0000 0005 2A61 3246 STAC..]*....a*F2
```

Looking at it from the top this is `fl`, `cs`, `ip`, `bp`, `ax` all from after running the prior instruction again. The next word is the `ip` of what was just executed at offset 0003h, set by `run` again.

Further on:

```
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=0200 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0008 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0008 E81100            call    001C
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 0005 2A5D-0000 0008 2A61 3246 STAC..]*....a*F2
```

This again has `fl`, `cs`, `ip`, `bp`, `ax`, all from after running the prior instruction. And 0005h as the prior `ip`.

```
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FE BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=001C NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:001C E8F8FF            call    0017
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 4341 2A5D 0000-001C 2A61 3246 000B STAC]*....a*F2..
```

000Bh is the newly pushed near return address of the `call 001C`. After that the outgoing `fl`, `cs`, `ip`, `bp`, and `ax`. The low word of the incoming `eip` is not found here because the `call` pushed a word onto the stack, so the five register values written by lDebug's `intr1` overwrote the entire `iretd` stack frame.

```
-
AX=2A5D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FC BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0017 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0017 B409              mov     ah, 09
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  5453 2A5D 0000 0017-2A61 3246 001F 000B ST]*....a*F2....
```

This shows another near return address word on the stack. Nothing else of note here.

```
-
AX=095D BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FC BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=0019 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:0019 CD21              int     21
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 214B 2121-5453 4341 214B 2121 STACK!!!STACK!!!
2A3D:01F0  0017 095D 0000 0019-2A61 3246 001F 000B ..].....a*F2....
```

Here we still have the two near return addresses on the stack, 000Bh then 001Fh. After that as usual `fl`, `cs`, `ip`, `bp`. Then we have a word reading 095Dh which is the new `ax` value also pushed by `intr1`, with the `ah` value now changed to 09h. After that the `iretd` frame's `eip` shows up again, as 0017h.

```
-
Eat at Joe's...AX=0924 BX=0000 CX=0266 DX=0000 SP=01FC BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
DS=2A5D ES=2A2D SS=2A3D CS=2A61 IP=001B NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC
2A61:001B C3                retn
header     0    2    4    6    8    A    C    E    0123456789ABCDEF
2A3D:01E0  5453 4341 0924 0000-0266 0000 0000 0000 STAC$...f.......
2A3D:01F0  0000 2A5D 2A2D 001C-2A61 3246 001F 000B ..]*-*..a*F2....
```

For completeness: This still has 000Bh and 001Fh as the near return addresses. Then `fl`, `cs`, `ip`. A `bp` and `ax` value from `intr1` are not on this stack because the `int 21h` instruction is proceeded past by writing an `int3` instruction (single-byte opcode 0CCh). So [the `intr3` entrypoint](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/e3b083561c33/source/run.asm#l6096) is used.

After that there's some more values on the stack: the application's `es`, `ds`, `bp`, `di`, `si`, `dx`, `cx`, `bx`, `ax`.

This is from [the kernel's interrupt 21h handler](https://github.com/FDOS/kernel/blob/c08313ab62ed236fc9a11f1c558cc335b93de30c/kernel/entry.asm#L258). It uses [a macro defined in stacks.inc](https://github.com/FDOS/kernel/blob/c08313ab62ed236fc9a11f1c558cc335b93de30c/hdr/stacks.inc#L89):

```
%macro  PUSH$ALL  0
                push    es
                push    ds
                push    bp
                push    di
                push    si
                push    dx
                push    cx
                push    bx
                push    ax
%endmacro
```

Note that the kernel returns `al` as 24h (the dollar sign terminator), [as documented in the Interrupt List](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2109.html#2601). You can also see here that the kernel uses this stack frame to return the `ax` value (and all other 16-bit 8086 registers) so we get the return value of the interrupt call, not the value on entry.

---

Finally, looking at your question's values:

7346h, 0D16h, 0003h are the interrupt stack frame. The next 0D16h is the low word of `cs` from [the stack frame built for `iretd`](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/version-1.25/DEBUG.ASM#l7715). The 0000_0000h is the initial `eip` from the `iretd` frame.

Second step: 0005h is the returning `ip`, matching the offset of the disassembly at this point. 0000_0003h is the incoming `eip` of the `iretd` stack frame.

Subsequent steps work in the same way as I described for lDebug, except that like lDebug's `intr3` [the `intr01` entry of FreeDOS Debug/X](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/fddebug/file/version-1.25/DEBUG.ASM#l7750) does not push anything to the user application stack before switching to the debugger's stacks.

I reviewed the source of v1.25 of FreeDOS Debug/X, which was released on 2011-08-07 so it is the latest version you could have used on 2018-05-28.